# how to hide a Blank row in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

At the moment I'm working on the Database PHP for MySQL, I am using on MySQL Workbench tools, it looks great but I have one tiny problem, (as I'm still newbie rank in MySQL administrator)

Here is a code I wrote

```
SELECT
    sku,
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'order' AND amount_description = 'Principal' AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice',amount,0)) AS 'Total_Order',
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'order' AND amount_description = 'Principal' AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice', quantity_purchased,0)) AS 'Total_QTY_Order',
    SUM(IF(amount_type = 'FBA Inventory Reimbursement' AND amount_description = 'REVERSAL_REIMBURSEMENT',amount,0)) AS 'Total_Reimbursement',
    SUM(IF(amount_type = 'FBA Inventory Reimbursement' AND amount_description = 'REVERSAL_REIMBURSEMENT',quantity_purchased,0)) AS 'Total_QTY_Refund'
FROM settlements_qty_test

GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY Total_Order DESC
```

The results look fine and great but one thing is annoyed me as you can see the blue highlight, How do I hide this blue highlight as it's empty row. it's nothing there as no SKU on it.

[image]

I assumed this is due to null value or no null value?

Comment: Have you any **null values** or **zero length string** or **blank string** in `sku` field in `settlements_qty_test` table?

Comment: Just add `WHERE sku <> ''`

Comment: Yes, sku has a "Yes NULL"  in MySQL, there is a one blank string in the sku field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `GROUP BY` statement, insert a filter criterion. Maybe

```
  HAVING sku IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(sku) > 0
```

will do the trick. But it's hard to tell for sure how your missing `sku` value is actually recorded in the database.

Comment: It's work perfect as the blank sku has no feature and nothing relation to another field